# How to put a div in front of another div?

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to block users to click anywhere on the page except just on top div with a button.

```css
.topdiv {
  height: 90px;
}

.divBlocking {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  cursor: wait;
}
```

```html
<div class="topdiv" *ngIf="!blockContent">
  <button>Cancel</button>
</div>
<div class="divBlocking" *ngIf="blockContent"></div>

<div class="divApp">
  //application content/form/inputs
</div>
```

So whole screen is not clickable including the `tobdiv` than I don't want to. Changing `divBlocking=>top: 90;` seems not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `topdiv` class with `position: fixed;` and `z-index: 999;`

```css
.topdiv {
  height: 90px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
}

.divBlocking {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  cursor: wait;
}
```

```html
<div class="topdiv" *ngIf="!blockContent">
  <button>Cancel</button>
</div>
<div class="divBlocking" *ngIf="blockContent"></div>

<div class="divApp">
  //application content/form/inputs
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply **add `z-index: -1` to `.divBlocking`**.
This means send `.divBlocking` to the back.

To show case the difference, I add some background color.

**Your original code result like this**
[image]

**Add `z-index: -1` to `.divBlocking`**
[image]

## Edited code

```css
.topdiv{
      height:90px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    .divBlocking{
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      cursor: wait;
      background-color:rgba(201, 76, 76, 0.3);
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="topdiv" *ngIf="!blockContent"> 
     <button>Cancel</button>
</div>
<div class="divBlocking" *ngIf="blockContent"></div>

<div class="divApp"> 
     //application content/form/inputs
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of CSS is that you can determine the stack order of elements by using the [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

> In the most basic cases, HTML pages can be considered two-dimensional,
>   because text, images, and other elements are arranged on the page
>   without overlapping. In this case, there is a single rendering flow,
>   and all elements are aware of the space taken by others. The z-index
>   attribute lets you adjust the order of the layering of objects when
>   rendering content.

[Understanding the z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index)